# Format null as blank with Scala formatLocal

Tags: scala, string-formatting

We are using `"%,.2f".formatLocal(locale, value)`. Unfortunately `value`can be null and then it prints nu. We don't want it to print anything at all if the `value` is null. Is there a Scala idiom for this?

Comment: Scala tends not to have special handling for "null" since there are better ways of handling an exceptional value in Scala (Option etc.). However, what's wrong with `if (value == null) "" else "%,.2f".formatLocal(locale, value)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scala idiom for variables that may have no meaningful value is `Option`.  You can convert an object that may be `null` to an `Option` using `Option.apply`:

```
Option(3.14f : java.lang.Float) //Some(3.14)
Option(null : java.lang.Float) //None
```

And then you can use the idiomatic `Option` methods like `foreach`, `map`, `fold`, and `getOrElse` for the desired effect:

```
val myOptionString = myOptionFloat.map("%,.2f".formatLocal(locale, _))

myOptionString.foreach(println) //only print if the Float is not null   
val myString = myOptionString.getOrElse("") //empty string if the Float is null
```

Or all together for printing:

```
Option(myFloat).foreach(value => println("%,.2f".formatLocal(locale, value))
```

And for storing:

```
Option(myFloat).fold("")("%,.2f".formatLocal(locale, _))
```

Comment: Thanks! I like `Option(myFloat).fold("")("%,.2f".formatLocal(locale, _))` but I'm afraid it will confuse the Java programmers in our team so we might stick to `if (value == null) "" else "%,.2f".formatLocal(locale, value)`

Comment: Sure I understand that.  You might try to ease Java programmers in with `Option(myFloat).map(value => "%,.2f".formatLocal(locale, value)).getOrElse("")`, which is a little easier to read (doesn't use the underscore syntax, and uses `getOrElse` instead of `fold`).  Once they start getting used to Scala's terse and expressive syntax, there's no turning back!